# How is SegWit a soft fork?

Tags: transaction-verification, segregated-witness, soft-fork

Reading [this section](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki#serialization) of BIP144, I noticed the followng statement:

> Parsers supporting this BIP will be able to distinguish between the old serialization format (without the witness) and this one. The marker byte is set to zero so that this structure will never parse as a valid transaction in a parser that does not support this BIP. If parsing were to succeed, such a transaction would contain no inputs and a single output.

And this is in fact confirmed by [this line](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/1b046603b30ebfab6199a2f92015d507b248b590/src/validation.cpp#L495) in Bitcoin Core which is executed for every transaction found in a block during the `CheckBlock` call.

As far as I understand, this should mean that old clients that see a block containing a SegWit transaction would consider that transaction invalid and hence discard the whole block. Is that correct? What am I missing?

Comment: Actually, the line of code you're citing checks whether a transaction has 0 inputs, which is not allowed ever. To see the code that decides whether a witness is present, look at primitives/transaction.h.

Comment: @PieterWuille Yes, I was citing that line to reinforce the fact that old clients seeing the marker as '0x00' would interpret it as as the varint that specifies the number of inputs and hence refuse the transaction because it has zero inputs

Comment: Yes, I know. But again, you're confusing the abstract object with the serialization. In a transaction, 0 inputs is invalid. But the conversion from bytes to transaction object is elsewhere. A segwit transaction does not have 0 inputs, it just uses an encoding that looks like 0 inputs to old clients. Look in primitives/transaction.h for the deserialization code.

Comment: That makes no sense, if it looks like 0 inputs to the old client and 0 inputs is never valid, then indeed it will look invalid to the old client, won't it?         In any case, that seems to be a minor point. If the transaction now doesn't contain the signatures, how could it possibly look valid to someone not seeing the signatures?

Comment: @relG SegWit scripts look like ANYONECANSPEND scripts to old clients (i.e. everyone can spend a script which consists only of `OP_0 <32-byte push>` without needing a signature) so old clients that will see an ANYONECANSPEND output being spent with no signature will consider it a perfectly valid transactions

Comment: So can't, indeed, anyone spend it, at least from the point of view of the old nodes? And then there will be a fork of the network, cause someone except the legit user will spend it, and the new nodes reading the segwit witness will not accept this send, but the old ones will?

Comment: A softfork is defined as a consensus change that converges as long as majority of the hashrate adopts it. Yes, a non-witness transaction spending a segwit output without signature would be valid to old nodes, but 1) they won't see that (such a transaction is nonstandard to everyone) 2) such a transaction won't be mined (same as 2) and thus 3) the majority chain will not accept such transactions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're confusing transactions (the abstract object) and their serialization (the bytes on the wire in the P2P protocol or on disk).

Sure, SegWit introduces an extension to the P2P protocol (BIP144), which relays witnesses along with transactions, and old clients wouldn't understand such messages.

But old clients don't see them. Witnesses are only included when the requester asks for them, which old clients don't do. For them, new clients remove the witnesses before relay. Exactly because the witness of a transaction does not contribute to its txid, it is in fact possible to remove them before relay, without invalidating them. That is what makes it a soft fork.

Comment: Ok, I see, so if I understand correctly, when an old client receives a block it will receive the block stripped of all witness-related data. Is that correct?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like (and is) a totally old style block to them.

Comment: how can? the old style block contains signature (witness) but the new and stripped one does not.

Comment: The new one contains empty signatures, which are valid according to the old rules, for spending SegWit outputs. SegWit just introduces an extra field to transaction (the witness), which does not contribute to the txid. The old scriptSig field is still there, but just unused for SegWit spends.

Comment: If a block contains empty signatures, how can the transactions be verified?

Comment: To an old client, all spends from SegWit outputs look like anyone-can-spend outputs, which are valid to spend without signature. Old spends still have signatures, which validate. New clients will also validate SegWit spends, by using the signatures from the witness.

Comment: @PieterWuille, And how is this different from SegWit2?

Comment: SegWit2X is an incompatible change to Bitcoin's rules sought by a number of companies, which will likely become a separate currency. It has nothing to do with Segwit.

Comment: Why is the empty signature there in the first place? Isn't it wasting space?

Comment: Yes, 1 byte of waste per input, which can be trivially removed by using a compressed transaction format. There are dozens of ways more inefficiencies exist - 4 bytes for timestamps, sequence numbers in all inputs, locktimes in all outputs, DER encoded signatures... each of those accounts for far more waste in terms of naively-counted block space. But for backward compatibility reasons it's not really worth the effort to fix them.